# Screen orientation change on fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation, samsung-mobile

I need to detect screen orientation change on a fragment and to do so, I am currently using this method:

```
public void onEvent(OrientationEvent event){...}
```

which works absolutely fine on my Nexus 4.
The problem I have is that on a Samsung Galaxy S3, the method is not called when rotating the screen. Anybody has an idea?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good Google webpage on this @ [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).  This covers when user changes screen between horizontal/vertical view, and switching applications. Code snippet:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The code above can be placed in the Activity or the Fragment subclass.

In your manifest xml, you set:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation">
```

Please keep us posted, I would like to know of your progress. Someday I may want to do this also. And I would code it like this, if I do

Comment: Many thanks for your help. But your solution goes for Activities only I think. I want to detect screen detection on a Fragment.

Comment: @thomaus, I tried it and, believe it or not, it works!  Remember that a Fragment can easily get the parent Activity by getActivity(). I admit you had me worried, and I thought I had to tell you that you have to add onConfigurationChanged override method in your Main activity and pass the info to the Fragment, which is an option.

Comment: For better clarity, onConfigurationChanged() can be placed in the Fragment subclass too.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getScreenOrientation(){    
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    return "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT";
else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    return "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE";
else
    return "";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the method onConfigurationChange() in your fragment simplly. You can have look at this developer android post :

> **public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)**
>
> **Called by the system when the device configuration changes while your**
> **component is running.** Note that, unlike activities, other components
> are never restarted when a configuration changes: they must always
> deal with the results of the change, such as by re-retrieving
> resources.
>
> At the time that this function has been called, your Resources object
> will have been updated to return resource values matching the new
> configuration.
>
> Parameters
>
> **newConfig**     The new device configuration.

Inside onConfigurationChanged, You need to check the current orientation like :

```
newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
```

and add logic